Desktop file for Wine program works with gtk-launch but not from dock
When I installed a program under Wine (v9.0), it generated some .desktop files under ~/.local/share/applications/wine/Programs/LTspice. It shows up in the app launcher but does nothing when selected.
I have been changing it trying to get it work for the last hour with no success. Currently it looks like this.
[Desktop Entry]
Name=LTspice
Exec=env WINEPREFIX="/home/me/.wine" /opt/wine-stable/bin/wine /home/me/.wine/dosdevices/c:/users/me/AppData/Local/Programs/ADI/LTspice/LTspice.exe
Type=Application
StartupNotify=true
Path=/home/me/.wine/dosdevices/c:/users/me/AppData/Local/Programs/ADI/LTspice/
Icon=B1B0_LTspice_1.0
StartupWMClass=ltspice.exe

Copy-pasting the Exec line into a terminal opens LTspice just fine. If I move this file to ~/.local/share/applications, gtk-launch LTspice successfully launches the program (because apparently gtk-launch has different search behavior from the app launcher). Still, opening it from the dock or from the app launcher results in a spinning cursor for a few seconds then nothing.
I have made sure the .desktop file is executable and right clicked and selected "Allow Launching" in Nautilus.
Of course, there are no error messages and I can't get a terminal to stay open to actually tell me what is going wrong.
I have also just made a few other .desktop files with no issue for a few other programs (non-wine though).

Seems that there was an old broken version of the file that was cached somewhere, so all the edits I was doing were not being seen. After rebooting, the shortcut in the dock works fine now. If others have this problem, perhaps these answers would provide a better solution than rebooting.
